# Cambio de dominio pagina web wordpress, productos adquiridos en godaddy

Tags: wordpress, dominio, godaddy

Estimad@s compre un dominio y hosting a traves de godaddy, pero ahora me arrepentí del nombre de la página. Es posible cambiar la dirección de la pagina a otra totalmente distinta?.

Comment: el dominio lo compré el pasado 15 de septiembre.

Comment: Tienes que revisar la política de devolución del registrador de dominio. Si fue el 15 de septiembre quizá estés dentro del plazo en que lo puedes devolver. Sino, deberás comprar el nuevo dominio, subir todo el contenido a él y desactivar la renovación del dominio que ya no quieres.

Comment: Realmente esta consulta se la debes hacer a la asistencia técnica del proveedor del dominio, nosotros aquí no podemos solucionar esos temas.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar la dirección de tu wordpress, eso se hace en el panel de administración, provisto que compres el dominio de la nueva dirección y apunte a la misma máquina. Ojo con Godaddy. La modalidad más común es que ofrezcan dominio+hosting de regalo, pero en realidad tú pagas el hosting. El dominio queda indirectamente a nombre de ellos y no es trivial llevárselo a otro registrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si compraste el dominio en GoDaddy y quieres gozar de su política de reembolsos **debes darte prisa**.

Para nuevos registros, ellos te devuelven el dinero si solicitas cancelación **dentro de los cinco días posteriores a la transacción**.  Es decir, tienes hasta hoy día 20 para cancelar y poder usar el dinero en la compra de tu otro dominio. En caso contrario, tendrás que conservar el dominio que no quieres hasta su expiración, asegurándote de que cualquier renovación automática esté desactivada y comprar el nuevo dominio en el que subirás el contenido del sitio.

Esto es lo que ellos indican en su [Política de reembolsos](https://www.godaddy.com/agreements/showdoc?pageid=19963&prog_id=PROG_ID):

### Domain Name Registrations/Renewals

#### 1.      Standard Terms

- New Registration............................5 Days (120 Hours)
- Auto-Renewal (one-year).............45 Days (1080 hours)
- Auto-Renewal (multiple-year).........5 Days (120 Hours)
- Manual Renewal.............................5 Days (120 Hours)

Hay excepciones en dominios con extensión `.mx`, `.pe`, `.au` ... y otros. Están todas indicadas por ellos en el mismo enlace.